# this.$.id só retorna undefined

Tags: javascript, id, load, polymer

Estou usando Polymer 2.x, estou tentando fazer um pré-load para a página, fiz uma div com um gif de load e vou tirar com setTimeout... Porém no script quando uso a função this.$.load ele retorna undefined. Alguém poderia me ajudar a colocar display none na div?

Segue o código

```
ready(){
   super.ready();
   setTimeout(function(){
     this.$.load.classList.add('hidden'); //Classe adiciona display none
   }, 4000);
}

<div id="load">
   <img src="/* GIF */" alt="Loading..."/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui resolver, criei uma variável para guardar o this, e a usei para adicionar a classe. Segue abaixo

```
ready(){
    super.ready();
    var element = this
    setTimeout(function(){
      element.$.load.classList.add('hidden');
    }, 4000);
  }
```